# VB.NET How to limit the number of selected cells in a data grid view

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make an airline system with a seat selector with the use of a DataGridView. How am I supposed to limit the number of selected cells of the user?

Is it like this?

DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count = 5

Or there is no way to do that?

Comment: No, that's read-only.  You need to handle the SelectionChanged event of DataGridView and validate the user selection there, either adjusting the selection, or alerting the user to the limitation.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: My guess is you will want to keep the list of "selected" cells in a list, or other data structure, and not use the DGVs selection. You can use the individual cell's style to change the back color of the selected seats.

Comment: Please make your question clear. What do you mean by limiting the number of selected cells of the user?

Do you mean that you want to limit so that user can select only a fixed number of cells i.e., max 5 columns per user.

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. When it fires, it checks if the number of selections is greater than 5 and deselects the last cell selected.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    With DataGridView1
        If .SelectedCells.Count > 5 Then
            .SelectedCells(.SelectedCells.Count - 1).Selected = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```